# CORS issue with oauth if redirected to Account/Login from [Authorized]

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, cors

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        return new ChallengeResult(
            GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                RedirectUri = Url.Action(nameof(LoginCallback), new { returnUrl })
            });
    }
...
```

I have the controller shown above. If I type `https://localhost:44378/Account/Login` in the browser address bar it works fine - I get redirected to the Google authorization page but if I get redirected to this endpoint by hitting `[Authorize]` or a similar attribute on another endpoint I'm getting error like the following one:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?...' (**redirected from**
> 'https://localhost:44378/api/some-action') from origin
> 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

JIC, I added `http://localhost:3000` to both *Authorized JavaScript origins* and *Authorized redirect URIs* in the app registration Google page.

Why so and how to solve it?

EDIT:
Network:
[image]

EDIT2:

I created test project with frontend and backend on the same port, the issue persists

> (redirected from 'https://localhost:44336/weatherforecast') from origin 'https://localhost:44336' has been blocked by CORS policy

Answer (score -1):

The local HTTP server (the one that is serving `https://localhost:[Port]/...` needs to be configured to respond to HTTP OPTIONS request with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*'` in the response headers.

In case of cross domain requests, Browsers(especially chrome) make a HTTP OPTIONS request for the same endpoint before HTTP GET or HTTP POST

Comment: I believe I'm getting this error from accounts.google.com. My backend server is configured to accept CORS requests from my frontend.

Answer (score -1):

Try with this in your Startup.cs file.

this inside the class -> readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

and this inside the ConfigureServices method

```
services.AddCors(options =>
        {
           options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                              builder =>
                              {
                                  builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
                              });
         });
```

change the address and port with yours

you can check this link as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: I have a similar line for `localhost:3000` it works fine between frontend and backend. The problem happens when redirect to accounts.google.com happens.