# CORS IAP problem between 2 App engine services

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, cors, in-app-purchase

I really tried finding the solution in other posts but have been stuck for days..

My setup consists of following:

- Flask backend running on Google App Engine flexible service
- Vue.js frontend running on Google App Engine standard service

Both are running inside the same project and the same app engine but have different subdomains. Both of them are protected by two IAP policies (same users though).

When i open up the GAE frontend, i receive following error in console:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id={blablabla}' (redirected from 'https://backend-dot-project.ew.r.appspot.com/get_data') from origin 'https://frontend-dot-project.ew.r.appspot.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

In the network tab it is the status code 302, which indicates that the request is being temporarily redirected. I have set up a logging in the backend to see incoming requests -> there are no "get_data" requests arriving.

Now to the interesting part: The problem goes away when i open up the backend. Even visiting the backend subdomain once is enough for the IAP problem to go away.

Deleting cookies is causing the problem to re-appear. Until i visit the backend once again.

Is there a some kind of programmatic authentication needed? Or do i need to send some kind of IAP data within my requests?

Things i already did:

- Activating the http preflight options for the IAP in the console
- When making AJAX requets in the frontend: { withCredentials: true }
- CORS Backend allowed origins configuration set up correctly:

  CORS(main, resources={r"/*": {"origins": 'https://frontend-dot-project.ew.r.appspot.com'}}, supports_credentials=True)

I noticed that this fellow sufferer had the same problem 2 years ago but nobody seemed to solve it:
[CORS issue with oauth if redirected to Account/Login from [Authorized]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66837349/cors-issue-with-oauth-if-redirected-to-account-login-from-authorized?rq=2)

Comment: You mentioned that you have set up CORS configuration on your backend, which is good. However, make sure it's set up correctly. It should allow the origin (frontend) that is making the request. Verify that the configuration includes the correct frontend URL with the supports\_credentials option set to True. `withCredentials: Setting { withCredentials: true }` in your frontend's AJAX requests is essential to send cookies and authentication headers. This is necessary for IAP to properly authenticate the request.